# Adding Podcasts to Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0, sync, podcast, nokia-lumia-820

Anybody knows how to add a podcast to a windows phone 8 device?
The Windows 8 app doesn't have that option. Adding them directly to the file system makes them show up in Music, and that's not where they should be.

Zune worked so well...

Comment: Is this the same question http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/how-are-podcasts-managed-on-the-file-system-in-wp8?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Comment: SOLUTION: Use http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Music + Videos app. Podcasts will be under the Collection menu. Yu can search and add podcasts from there as well as play them. Only other way is to use another podcast app or iTunes.

Comment: I see the podcasts under Music in the Music + Videos app. When I open the Podcasts there, no podcasts are listed and it instructs me to go to the store. I don't want to go to the store, I want to download the podcasts from my laptop and push them to the phone. Do I need iTunes for this? I hate iTunes and I won't install it.

Comment: Yes, you would need iTunes for that. Podcasts took a step backwards with WP8. WP7 and Zune worked damn well for me.